# excel hyperlink a vlookup partial string match

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vlookup

I have a VLOOKUP formula for a partial string match like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE("*",B3,"*"),$A$2:$A$3,1,FALSE)
```

which results in 2013-BROWN.TOM.PDF

I want to hyperlink the result of the VLOOKUP like this:

C:\JP\TEST\2013-BROWN.TOM.PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you could accomplish this by simply adding that data into your formula - Something along the lines of:

```
=HYPERLINK("C:\JP\TEST\" & VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE("*",B3,"*"),$A$2:$A$3,1,FALSE))
```

But if I'm not understanding your question, please clarify...

Comment: :) Glad it did!! - Also, a **slight** efficiency in your formula could be to replace `CONCATENATE("*",B3,"*")` with `"*" & B3 & "*"` ... But it's not a big efficiency / saving...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. One more thing, I don't want it to show NA instead make it blank. How do I do that?

Comment: Have a look at the `IfError` function.... You can make it do whatever you want if the formula returns an error - In your case it would be `IFERROR(...your formula...,"")`